# Highlight set of case-insensitive substrings in a long string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Given a long string in JavaScript, like "Ruby on Rails", and an input string like "ru ra", how could you produce something like `<strong>Ru</strong>by on <strong>Ra</strong>ils`, i.e. **Ru**by on **Ra**ils?

My first thought was to tokenize each set of strings and iterate through both sets of tokens, looking for matches, and constructing the new result string as I went. However, I'm not sure how performant this approach is and I often got duplicates. For example, the input "ruby on r" would match for "Ruby" twice, and for "Rails" once.

Comment: You've pretty much got the algorithm: parse the content of text nodes and split into new nodes and span elements. You may have to deal with matching "ru" in `<b>R</b>uby`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var original = "Ruby on Rails";
var find = "ru ra";
var posToAdd = [];
var newStr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    newStr.push(original.charAt(i));
}

find = find.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    for (var e = 0; e < find.length; e++) {
        if (original.substring(i, find[e].length + i).toLowerCase() == find[e].toLowerCase()) {
            posToAdd.push(i);
        }
    }
}
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < posToAdd.length; i++) {
    newStr.splice(posToAdd[i] + count, 0, "<strong>");
    newStr.splice(posToAdd[i] + count + (find[i].length + 1), 0, "</strong>");
    count += 2;
}
var outputStr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    outputStr += newStr[i];
}
print(outputStr);
```

Comment: srry for no indent :P

Comment: If the string is blank or contains no matches, some of these `.length`'s will error.

Comment: then add some if statements :P